# errorInvalid / used nonce - Twitter oauth - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I have a server which is polling for mentions from Twitter. It works great in my test environment, but in production it started to fail after a while.

I use the twitter_oauth gem 0.4.0. I cant see whats different in production.

```
client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new(
  :consumer_key => 'k7P---------gTQ',
  :consumer_secret => 'PDWa-------------ThaOBM',
  :token => '1608769-------------------------igwp0YzHslh',
  :secret => '00L-------------------------CZfZTt0'
)

last_index = self.fetch_message_index

s = client.mentions
```

It worked for a while, but now it just works in the test-environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the time was out of sync on my server. When I adjusted the clock, everything started to work again.